# Factorial of 100 numbers

Tags: java

This program keep returns "Factorial of 100 is 0" for every 100 numbers as output.
where is the problem?

```
public class Factorial4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=1; i<=100; i++){
            System.out.println("Factorial of " + i + " is " + factorial(i));
        }
    }

    public static int factorial(int n){ 
        int result = 1;
        for (int i=1; i<=100; i++){
            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are never using the value n

Comment: I define "n" as parameter for the method. So, if the problem is "parameter of the method", how can I define a parameter for a method, correctly?

Comment: factorial of 100 is larger than `int` range. Actually, factorial of 13 is already larger than `int` range

Comment: @Shirin defining the variable doesn't mean you're using it inside the method.

Comment: You never use `n` inside the method, look more carefully at the for loop of `factorial`

Comment: I understood that I cannot calculate factorial of integers upper than 14 with this code. Now, consider I make it 10, instead of 100. why it keep returns 0? how should I define the "n" as parameter for this method? thank you

Comment: Look at Elliott Frisch's code for one example, you should use `n` that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` not `100`.

```
public static int factorial (int n){
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) { // <-- n, not 100.also, x*1=x
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Of note, is that `int` would overflow at `100!` so you could use a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) like

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) { // <-- n, not 100.also, x*1=x
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this code has multiple issues:

1. you always create the factorial of 100 (loop runs until 100).
2. factorial will create values that are by far bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. you'll have to use `BigInteger` instead. The 0 is simply a result of tons of overflows.

Comment: So, this "0" is result of "overflow"? or is it the "default value" of "n"? (since I know java considers "0" as a default value for integers, if we don't initialize them), right?

Comment: its the result of an overflow. in binary, it would look like this: 1 * 10 * ... * 100 * ... * 1000 * ... * .... . this means: after multiplying by 10, the lowest bit is 0, after multiplication with 100, the 3 lowest bits are 0, and so on, until all bits are 0, which would be 0 in decimal aswell.

Answer (score 0):

The correct logic would be

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n){ 
    BigInteger result = 1;
    for (int c=1; c<=n; c++){
        result =result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(c));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using BigInteger would make sense because `result` would exceed `int` range

Comment: This would return an odd result when passing 14 or a greater value as parameter.

Comment: Go all the way for `BigInteger`

Answer (score 0):

Integer range problem... for small 'n' you can use long (for 'result'), for larger ones - double.